# A sliding seekBar in android instead of tapping seekBar with the progress change is disabled till an event finishes

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am implementing a seekBar in my app and I want to make it sliding based instead of tapping based. But once the user has done with the sliding, instead of changing the progress, the seekBar has to wait for an event to be completed and based on the response of the event, the progress in the seekBar will be changed respective to the sliding value.

```
The flow will be like:- slide the seekBar--on sliding finished wait for an event to be finished--once the event finished, make the corresponding progress change based on the sliding.


Below I am posting my code.

The custom seekBar class:

    public class Slider extends SeekBar {

        private Drawable mThumb;

        public Slider(Context context) {
            super(context);

        }

        public Slider(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

        }

        @Override
        public void setThumb(Drawable thumb) {
            super.setThumb(thumb);
            mThumb = thumb;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                if (event.getX() >= mThumb.getBounds().left
                        && event.getX() <= mThumb.getBounds().right
                        && event.getY() <= mThumb.getBounds().bottom
                        && event.getY() >= mThumb.getBounds().top) {

                    super.onTouchEvent(event);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                return false;
            } else {
                super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

            return true;
        }}

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Fragment where the seekBar is implemented:

     viewHolder.dimming.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                                    int originalProgress;
                                    @Override
                                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                                        originalProgress = seekBar.getProgress();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                                        if(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                                        {
                                            if(seekBar.isShown() && fromUser)
                                            {

                                                progress= (progress/10)*10;
                                                //ProgressUtil.showProgressDialog(progressDialog);
                                                Log.d("Seek", String.valueOf(progress));
                                                viewHolder.dimming.setEnabled(false);
                                                handleDCURequest.slc_dimming((Context)myContext,slcIDVal,progress, originalProgress,dcuIDVal,viewHolder.dimming);
                                                //adapter.getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).child("Percentage").setValue(progress);

                                                //viewHolder.showProgress.setText(progress+"%");
                                            }
                                        }



                                    }
                                });



I tried my best,but failed. Please do help. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Kindly post what you have tried till now.

Comment: @nipun.birla: please find the edited question above.